# how to use Pig to load CF/TABLE from Cassandra

Tags: load, cassandra, apache-pig

When I tried to load the table dataset from Cassandra via pig, I met some problems. Currently, the Cassandra version is 2.0.3.

Below is two row of my dataset

```
>the format is "user_name","tweet","user_id':
>chaaiinzz | RT @Luis_Cortes35: @3_chaaiinzz @jonaski720 @sarajanellxo @skylalopez man I love this Spanish class | 408845338091343872
>Jessicaokelley | Absolutely love the movie "The Mortal Instruments: City Of Bones!! | 408845337965907968
```

Create the keyspace and copy dataset to table twitters.

```
cqlsh:pxh130430> CREATE KEYSPACE cql3ks WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
cqlsh:pxh130430> use cql3ks;
cqlsh:cql3ks> CREATE TABLE twitters ( user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY, tweet varchar, user varchar);
cqlsh:cql3ks> COPY twitters (user, tweet, user_id) FROM '/tmp/nameT.csv' with delimiter = '|';
3625 rows imported in 2.142 seconds.
cqlsh:cql3ks> select count(*) from twitters;
count
-------
3620
(1 rows)
```

Load data in Pig

```
grunt> moretestvalues= LOAD 'cql://cql3ks/twitters/' USING CqlStorage;
grunt> describe moretestvalues;
moretestvalues: {user_id: chararray,tweet: chararray,user: chararray,user_id: chararray}
grunt> dump moretestvalues;
2013-12-08 22:09:19,337 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt -ERROR 1108: Duplicate schema alias: user_id in "moretestvalues"
Details at logfile: /Users/pengyuhou/apache-    cassandra/examples/pig/bin/pig_1386562141091.log
```

Actually, I only have three columns with one “user_id” column. I don’t know why pig results in two "user_id" columns.

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug which should be fixed with [Cassandra-6309](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6309)

Comment: Thanks!! do you know how to use the "6309-fix-pig-test-compiling.txt" to fix this bug?

Comment: You'll want to get the Cassandra Repo from github.
Apply the patch using 'git apply'.
Recompile Cassandra with 'ant build'.
Use your newly compiled Cassandra.

Comment: thank you. I've tried another way to use Cassandra 1.2 and Pig 0.7. Finally, it does work for me.

Comment: Would you like to check my another problem? Thanks! it's here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6466

Comment: Use the cqlstorage engine to get the easier to use formatting.